# Add an event to Microsoft Calendar with exceptions

Tags: windows-10, windows-10-calendar-app

I have an event that occurs every other Tuesday, except when that event would occur on the third Tuesday of the month; in that case, it occurs on that third Thursday of the month instead.

I added two recurring, never-ending, events to the Microsoft calendar for each time-frame but I have to manually go through the entire calendar for the rest of the year (or more) and remove the events where the exception overlaps with the regularly scheduled event or when the exception wouldn't occur because the normal Tuesday event wouldn't have happened anyway.

Is there a way to add logic either programmatically with an API or some feature of the windows 10 calendar app that I am not seeing that will let me set an event based on whether or not another event occurs?

Comment: I don't think there's an automated answer to your question, but just in case someone else knows one, this part is important: is there a repeating pattern in when a second thursday becomes a third thursday? For example "every two months"?